# A question about the Conner Conjecture

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, transformation-groups

In some sources, Conner conjecture is expressed as follows:

**Theorem** [Conner Conjecture] Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, and let $X$ have
the homotopy type of a finite dimensional $G$-CW complex with finitely many
orbit types. Then $\widetilde{H}^{\ast }\left( X;A\right) =0\Rightarrow 
\widetilde{H}^{\ast }\left( X/G;A\right) =0$.

In the article ''P. E. Conner. Retraction properties of the
orbit space of a compact topological transformation group'', I have never seen a statement like this.

It is stated that this theorem was first proven by Oliver,
''R. Oliver. A proof of Conner conjecture''

Oliver proved that if a compact Lie group $G$ acts on a space $X$, where $X$
is either paracompact of finite cohomological dimension and with finitely
many orbit types, or compact Hausdorff, then $X/G$ is $\mathbb{Z}
$-acyclic or $\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{p}$-acyclic ($p$ any prime, and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$) if $X$ is.

My question is that a finite dimensional $G$-CW complex is a paracompact of
finite cohomological dimension?

In other words, did Oliver prove the Conner conjecture for finite
dimensional $G$-CW complexes?

Comment: Any CW complex is paracompact, and any sensible notion of cohomological dimension should be bounded above by the dimension as a complex. So the answer is yes.

Comment: @MarkGrant Can you recommend a specific source for this?